# rails HABTM relation missmatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, relationship

I tried to make a HABTM relation for my project-model and i can't save it due this error `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ProjectsController#update` with this description `DockerService(#47111788307900) expected, got "" which is an instance of String(#47111734410780)` and i don't get my mistake. As i can see in the logs, there is everytime a empty entry in my `project_params[:docker_service]` and i don't know why. Maybe anyone can help me.

This is my project model:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  # belongs to
  belongs_to :user

  # has_many
  has_many :docker_services_projects
  has_many :docker_services, through: :docker_services_projects

  ...
end
```

my DockerServicesProjects model

```
class DockerServicesProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :docker_service
  belongs_to :project
end
```

and my DockerService model

```
class DockerService < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :docker_services_projects
  has_many :projects, through: :docker_services_projects
end
```

project_params from my ProjectsController:

```
def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(
        :user_id,
        :title,
        :description,
        :config,
        docker_services: [],
        documents: []
      )
    end
```

my form has this:

```
<%= form_with(model: project, local: true) do |form| %>
```

and

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.select :docker_services, options_from_collection_for_select(DockerService.all, :id, :title), {}, { multiple: true } %>
</div>
```

the update method looks like this:

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|

      puts project_params[:docker_services]

      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

when i log the params before the model gets saved i got this in my project_params:

```
"docker_services"=>["", "1", "2", "3"]
```

Comment: can you share the form method?

Comment: @demir I've added the update method and the form from the view :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the select field name, also you need to change the field name in the controller. It should be **docker_service_ids** instead of docker_services:

```
# _form.html.erb

<div class="field">
  <%= form.select :docker_service_ids, options_from_collection_for_select(DockerService.all, :id, :title), {}, { multiple: true } %>
</div>

# projects_controller.rb
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(
    :user_id,
    :title,
    :description,
    :config,
    docker_service_ids: [],
    documents: []
  )
end
```

Comment: thanks! That worked! Can you tell me why the service ids arent selected when i edit the entry again?

Comment: must be selected. Did you fix both form and project_params, right?

Comment: yeah. It saves the selected right in database table but they are not selected after save.

Comment: `options_from_collection_for_select` method has a selected parameter. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select .try this: `options_from_collection_for_select(DockerService.all, :id, :title, form.object.docker_service_ids)`